# Is the day/night cycle broken in Assassin's Creed: Liberation HD?

Tags: assassins-creed-3-liberation

Okay, this is kind of a weird question to ask. I've been playing *Assassin's Creed: Liberation HD*, the remastered version of *Assassin's Creed III: Liberation* on PC and I've noticed some strange behaviour in the day/night cycle.

First of all, it seems to randomly switch from day to night or vice-versa when restarting a mission, starting a new mission or fast travelling. The other thing is that it seems to get stuck there, too. It's particularly noticeable with the night part of the cycle. Neither the moon or the shadows seem to move. At first, I thought it was simply that the game doesn't have an actual day/night cycle. However, I took the time to pay attention to the shadows during the day and they actually move. Also, I looked it up and there's a sped-up video showing the complete cycle.

So, to summarize, is this a widespread issue? And more importantly, is there a fix? I know it doesn't affect the gameplay at all but it starts to become annoying after a while. Especially if you're stuck with the night part of the cycle.